# IE 11 fullpage.js anchor issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js on a site, and it's gone pretty smoothly so far, however, there seems to be an issue when resizing the window specifically in Internet Explorer.

The issue is that none of the links, which are set up using fullpage.js's data-anchors, work when the window is resized and I can't figure out why.

They're all lowercase, both in the href value and in the data-anchor of each section, and the site seems to be working absolutely fine on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Safari so as far as I can see the issue can be isolated to IE.

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Comment: Also asked here: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/3881

Comment: Can you post enough code or create a sample to reproduce the problem?